# Why can we obtain updated result from an argument passed as value to a method?

Tags: c#

In a program, there is a call to a method named `HandleHttpRequest` which takes in an argument of class `HttpContext`.

`HandleHttpRequest` processes an incoming request in `httpContext.Request` and writes a response to `httpContext.Response`.

My question is why after the call to `HandleHttpRequest` finishes, the program can obtain the response written to `httpContext.Response`?

Is `httpContext` passed as a value to `HandleHttpRequest`, instead of a reference, correct?

Thanks.

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/my.ashx", "timestamp=20170216");
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(textWriter);
HttpContext httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

HandleHttpRequest(httpContext);

textWriter.Flush();
byte[] buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
```

The signature of `HandleHttpRequest` is

```
public void HandleHttpRequest(HttpContext context)
```

So its argument isn't a reference.

Comment: `httpContext` is passed by value, but it is a reference to an instance of `HttpContext` so if it is mutated through the shared reference in `HandleHttpRequest` the changes will be visible.

Comment: You're passing in *the value of a reference* to an instance of `httpContext`. In plain English, you're passing in a reference to an instance of `HttpContext`. The method does stuff to that instance of `HttpContext` rather than creating a clone.

Comment: *"Is httpContext passed as a value to HandleHttpRequest, instead of a reference, correct?"* -- clearly, cannot be correct, because the behavior you're seeing is unmistakably that of the method operating on the same instance you gave it, rather than on a copy. Who told you `HandleHttpRequest` is getting a copy of `httpContext`, and why on earth did you for a moment believe it might be true?

Comment: @EdPlunkett it is stated almost everywhere that parameters are passed by value in C# by default, which can be a bit confusing in cases like this. They are indeed passed by value, but that value is not what one might think, for reference types.

Comment: @Evk Fair enough, I've seen more than one disexplanation that strove to confuse the issue by focusing on technicalities at the expense of semantics. Nevertheless it doesn't take much time with the language to understand what's really happening.

Comment: @Lee Thanks. But the signature of `HandleHttpRequest` is

   `public void HandleHttpRequest(HttpContext context)`.

So its argument isn't a reference.

Comment: `HttpContext` is a class, classes are reference types so `context` is a reference. That reference is copied when calling `HandleHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Lee are objects of classes always passed by reference, and variables of other primitive types always by value? Is this the same in C# and in java?

Comment: By default parameters are passed by value, the same as Java. Parameters can be passed by reference using the `ref` or `out` modifiers. Java doesn't support pass by reference at all.

Comment: @Lee  What is the definition of a reference type? Is  a reference type always a class type, an interface type, an array type, or a delegate type?

Comment: Value types are allocated inline, reference types are allocated on the GC heap and are accessed indirectly through the reference. The value of a reference type denotes the location of the allocated value. If you want the official definition, look at the CLR specification.

Answer (score 1):

> Is httpContext passed as a value to HandleHttpRequest, instead of a reference, correct?

`httpContext` variable is a reference to an instance of `HttpContext`. The reference is passed to the method so anything the method does will show after the method returns. But keep in mind the reference variable is passed to the method by value so the method cannot assign another reference to it.

Here is a small application which will clarify some of the confusion:

```
internal class Program {

   private static void Main(string[] args) {

      var p1 = new Person { Name = "George" };
      ChangeName( p1 );

      // This will have "George" because the method never operated
      // on the person passed to it. 
      var name = p1.Name;

      // Now we call this method which will change the name of the person
      // we are passing to it.
      ChangeName2( p1 );

      // Therefore, now it will have "Jerry"
      var name2 = p1.Name;

      var p2 = new Person { Name = "Kramer" };

      // Let's record this so we can compare it later
      var p2Before = p2;

      // Now we do the exact same thing we did when we passed by value,
      // but now we pass by ref.
      ChangeName( ref p2 );

      // This will have "Smith" 
      var name3 = p2.Name;

      // This will return false;
      var samePerson = p2 == p2Before;

      Console.Read();
   }

   public static void ChangeName(Person person) {
      // This is a whole new person
      var p = new Person() { Name = "Smith" };
      person = p;
   }

   public static void ChangeName2(Person person) {
      person.Name = "Jerry";
   }

   // This takes the reference and assigns a new person to the reference
   public static void ChangeName(ref Person person) {
      var p = new Person() { Name = "Smith" };
      person = p;
   }
}
```

[Try Me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/#)

Comment: Thanks. But the signature of `HandleHttpRequest` is

   `public void HandleHttpRequest(HttpContext context)`.

So its argument isn't a reference.

Comment: Actually it is a reference. The reference is passed in. But the reference itself is not passed by reference. This is why i wrote the sample app because it is not easy to understand right away. Study my app closely. If you still have a question, ask me.